# Recovering corrupted video file

Tags: video, vlc, quicktime, corrupt

I witnessed a car collision a couple of days ago while driving, and since I have a dash cam (Genius Full HD), I assumed I could send the video file of the collision to one of the drivers. The dash cam records in 3 minute segments, and it glitched on the video where the collision occurred, which corrupted that recording. When I tried to open it in Quicktime, it crashed with error message `QuickTime Player can't open "FILE5853.MOV" because the movie's file format isn't recognized.` Similarly, VLC does nothing when I tried to open it there, and produces the following Terminal output

```
VLC media player 2.1.5 Rincewind (revision 2.1.4-59-g5f258d5)
[0x101902a80] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0x100237b20] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x100850000] moov atom not found
[0x103946860] mp4 demux error: MP4 plugin discarded (no moov,foov,moof box)
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x10402ae00] moov atom not found
[0x103946860] avcodec demux error: Could not open FILE5853.MOV: Unknown error: 1094995529
[0x1092622a0] mp4 demux error: MP4 plugin discarded (no moov,foov,moof box)
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x10200ea00] moov atom not found
[0x1092622a0] avcodec demux error: Could not open FILE5853.MOV: Unknown error: 1094995529
```

Out of curiosity, I hexdumped FILE5853.MOV, and I know there's about 67 MB of something in there, but I have no way of getting the video. Any suggestion on how to get the video of there (if it's even possible) would be very appreciated.

Comment: this site's for programming questions, not repairing corrupted files... that being said, look at the file's first few bytes. if it doesn't look like an mp4 header, them you've probably just whatever random binary garbage the file was corrupted into, and it's unlikely to have any valid video data in it at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try [recover_mp4_to_h264](http://www.videohelp.com/software/recover-mp4-to-h264). You will need to provide a valid reference i.e. one of the intact segments.

```
Usage:
recover_mp4_to_h264 in_good_similar.mp4 --avcc
recover_mp4_to_h264 in_corrupted.mp4 out_video.h264 [out_audio.aac | out_audio.wav | out_audio.mp3] [<recorder>]
recover_mp4_to_h264 in_corrupted.mp4 out_video.h264 [--aac | --pcm | --mp3] [<recorder>]
```

Comment: There is also a great Perl library that worked well for me:  https://github.com/bookkojot/mp4fixer
It supports Windows, Linux, and Mac.

Comment: Written by @bukkojot

Comment: I recovered deleted files with "testdisk" on linux but the video files were corrupt/unplayable as-is. The perl library @jfbloom22 mentioned above worked to recover chunks of video by reconstructing the testdisk recovered files.